# "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled" in Vitest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, vite, vitest

I am using Vite and I've installed vitest

Error:

```
Details:                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                     
    SyntaxError: /home/durrantm/Dropnot/vite/thedeiscorecard-vite/src/App.test.tsx:  
 Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
 (6:27):                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                     
      4 | describe('test', () => {                                                                                                                   
      5 |   it('works', () => {                                                                                                                      
      6 |     render(<App/>);                                                                                                         
      7 |     const text = screen.getByText('vite');                                                                                                 
      8 |     expect(text).toBe(true);                                                                                                               
      9 |   })
```

My test is

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import App from './App';

describe('test', () => {
  it('works', () => {
    const result = render(<App/>);
    const text = screen.getByText('vite');
    expect(text).toBe(true);
  })
})
```

My package.json has Vite, Vitest, Jest, and Mocha:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vitest": "^0.29.8"
  }
```

My vitest config is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    include: ['**/*.test.tsx']
    // ...
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vitest` = `vite plugin` so whatever `vitest` can't do let `vite` take care:

vitest.config.ts

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: i think it helped but now I get a different error about describe not available but I'll post a new question for that